# Criando usuário MySQL com segurança

Tags: php, mysql, segurança

Por questões de segurança, quais os privilégios que um usuário de banco de dados deve, ou não deve ter?

[image: Quais devo marcar??]

Comment: Ele deve ter só os que precisar realmente. Ele não deve ter nenhum mais.

Comment: Nunca forneça, crie uma aplicação que realize toda conexão com o banco por meio do seu código

Answer (score 1):

Depende da função do utilizador no acesso à base de dados.
Por exemplo, um utilizador apenas para consulta de dados não deve ter acesso a "INSERT" ou "DELETE" apesar da lógica de negocio estar preparada para não fazer essas tarefas, se o utilizador, por alguma razão for usado indevidamente, irá conseguir ter mais permissões que o desejado.

Answer (score -2):

Isto dependerá de quais tarefas o usuário precisará executar no banco de dados. Por exemplo, o usuário de uma aplicação precisará dos privilégios básicos (select, insert, update e delete) mas em algumas aplicações poderá precisar criar tabelas temporárias ou mesmo uma view.

A melhor coisa a fazer é prover o mínimo necessário de permissões (o bloco "dados") e, dependendo do caso, garantir outras.

Nota, você pode ter mais de um usuário acessando o mesmo banco de dados, as vezes pode ser até interessante criar alguém para aplicação em si, outros para rotinas administrativas, backup, etc.